# How do I get a Method of a nested property?

Tags: java, reflection, javabeans

I have a class Foo that a property of the type Bar.

```
public class Foo {
    public Bar getBar() {

    }
}

public class Bar {
    public String getName();
}
```

Is there a helper class or method that gets you a `java.lang.reflect.Method` object of the name property of `Bar`, using `Foo.class` and "bar.name"?

There is a class called `PropertyUtils` in Commons BeanUtils, but its `getPropertyDescriptor()` only works for `Object` instances, not `Class` instances.

I realize it's not hard at all to implement one, but I'd like to leverage what's already available.

Also, the fact that I need a Method object is not a result of bad design(hope not). What I'm working on is pretty much a JavaBeans editor.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean: "public Bar getBar()" ?

Comment: I bet he did, otherwise the question doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Commons BeanUtils, `PropertyUtils.getPropertyDescriptors()` takes a `Class` as input and returns an array of `PropertyDescriptor`.

I don't know if it will return "nested" names such as `bar.name` but if not, it shouldn't be too hard to recurse on the result and construct your own list of nested names.

Just a quick sanity check though... does the world really need yet another JavaBeans editor?

Comment: Heh, it's not a JavaBeans editor per say, but a web form that borrows some concepts from JavaBeans editors.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go for nested support:
Depending on the use-case the retrieved classes could be cached. For instance in an datatable crud application where heavy filtering is used.

```
/**
 * Retrieves the type of the property with the given name of the given
 * Class.<br>
 * Supports nested properties following bean naming convention.
 * 
 * "foo.bar.name"
 * 
 * @see PropertyUtils#getPropertyDescriptors(Class)
 * 
 * @param clazz
 * @param propertyName
 * 
 * @return Null if no property exists.
 */
public static Class<?> getPropertyType(Class<?> clazz, String propertyName)
{
    if (clazz == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Clazz must not be null.");
    if (propertyName == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("PropertyName must not be null.");

    final String[] path = propertyName.split("\\.");

    for (int i = 0; i < path.length; i++)
    {
        propertyName = path[i];
        final PropertyDescriptor[] propDescs = PropertyUtils.getPropertyDescriptors(clazz);
        for (final PropertyDescriptor propDesc : propDescs)
            if (propDesc.getName().equals(propertyName))
            {
                clazz = propDesc.getPropertyType();
                if (i == path.length - 1)
                    return clazz;
            }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with MVEL or OGNL and skip the "I need the Method object" requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version from [djmj answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16826529/619753) with Java 8 streams returning Optional if anybody is interested.

```
/**
 * Retrieves the type of the property with the given name of the given Class.
 *
 * Supports nested properties following bean naming convention "foo.bar.name"
 *
 * @return Optional.empty if no property exists.
 * @see PropertyUtils#getPropertyDescriptors(Class)
 */
public static Optional<Class<?>> findPropertyType(@NotNull Class<?> clazz, @NotBlank String propertyName) {
  return Arrays.stream(propertyName.split("\\.")).reduce(
      Optional.ofNullable(clazz), // identity -> initial value of the accumulator
      (Optional<Class<?>> accOptClazz, String nextPropertyName) -> // accumulator with current value and next value from string
          stream(accOptClazz)
              .map((Class<?> accClazz) -> Arrays.stream(PropertyUtils.getPropertyDescriptors(accClazz)))
              .flatMap(Function.identity())
              .filter(propDesc -> propDesc.getName().equals(nextPropertyName))
              .findFirst().map(PropertyDescriptor::getPropertyType),
      (clazzA, clazzB) -> null // needed but useless combiner (only for parallel reduce)
  );
}

/**
 * Turns an Optional<T> into a Stream<T> of length zero or one depending upon whether a value is present.
 */
public static <T> Stream<T> stream(Optional<T> opt) {
  return opt.isPresent() ? Stream.of(opt.get()) : Stream.empty();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got here by trying to transform a Spring Data Sort to a Comparator.

```
public class ComparatorUtils {
    public static <T> Comparator<T> fromSort(Sort sort, Class<T> type) {
        final Iterator<Sort.Order> orderIterator = sort.iterator();
        final Sort.Order order = orderIterator.next();

        Comparator<T> comparator = fromSortOrder(order, type);
        while (orderIterator.hasNext()) {
            comparator = comparator.thenComparing(fromSortOrder(orderIterator.next(), type));
        }

        return comparator;
    }

    private static <T> Comparator<T> fromSortOrder(Sort.Order order, Class<T> type) {
        final List<Method> accessMethods = new ArrayList<>();
        Class<?> currentClass = type;

        for (String property : order.getProperty().split("\\.")) {
            Method m = Objects.requireNonNull(BeanUtils.getPropertyDescriptor(currentClass, property)).getReadMethod();
            accessMethods.add(m);
            currentClass = m.getReturnType();
        }

        Comparator<T> comparator = Comparator.comparing((T entity) -> {
            try {
                Object result = entity;
                for (Method method : accessMethods) {
                    result = method.invoke(result);
                }
                return (Comparable) result;
            } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder()));

        if (order.isDescending())
            return comparator.reversed();
        return comparator;
    }
}
```